# What do I gain from air drops?

Tags: dying-light

I'm at level 6 for my Survivor/Agility/Power skills in Dying Light, and while I've gotten a couple of air drops, have generally been ignoring them.

However, I'm having difficulty increasing my Survival skill because stronger enemies keep killing me and taking away my XP, so now am wondering if the air drops might provide some better weapons or something that can help my level.

Comment: What do you mean by "worth"?

Comment: Better weapons or other significant reason for spending the energy to chase after them?

Comment: How do you measure the worth?

Comment: Maybe rephrase your question from "is it worth" to "how can air drops help" or something

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Air drops are worth getting in the early game because after you open them, not only can you get flares/medical supplies that help you, but you can get drops that you can turn into the Quartermaster.

Doing so warrants you a lot of survivor points which can help with that problem of low Survivor skill.

You don't get weapons from them, although sometimes they contain grenades or such but it's most often flares/medical supplies and drops for the Quartermaster.

In my experience, Survivor rank was always behind the other two, and your best bet is Air Drops, encounters, and avoiding your death to get it up.

Comment: Excellent, that's what I needed to know... the Survivor XP gain.

Comment: Wow, I just got 5000 Survivor XP for returning an air drop to the quartermaster!

Comment: Yeah and I'm pretty sure it scales.